# Is it possible to move substrings to a specific location with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

Background: I used quill.js to get some rich text input. The result I want is quite similar to HTML so I went with the `quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML` approach instead of actually serializing the data. But when it comes to anchor, instead of

```
<a href="test.html">Anchor</a>
```

I actually want

```
Anchor{{link:test.html}}
```

With .replace() method I easily got `{{link:test.html}}Anchor</a>` but I need to put the link description after the Anchor text. Is there a way to swap `{{link:test.html}}` with the next `</a>` so I can get the desired result? There can be multiple anchors in the string, like:

```
str = 'This is a <a href="test1.html">test</a>. And <a href="test2.html">another one</a> here.'
```

I would like it to become:

```
str = 'This is a test{{link:test1.html}}. And another one{{link:test2.html}} here.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use capture groups and placeholders in the replacement string, provided it really is in exactly the format you've shown:

```js
const str = 'This is a <a href="test1.html">test</a>. And <a href="test2.html">another one</a> here.';
const result = str.replace(/<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>/g, "$2{{link:$1}}");
console.log(result);
```

This is **very** fragile, which is why famously you [don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454). For instance, it would fail with this input string:

```
const str = 'This is a <a href="test1.html">test <span>blah</span></a>. And <a href="test2.html">another one</a> here.';
```

...because of the `<span>blah</span>`.

But if the format is as simple and consistent as you appear to be getting from quill.js, you can apply a regular expression to it.

That said, if you're doing this on a browser or otherwise have a DOM parser available to you, use the DOM as [charlietfl demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549631/157247);

Comment: This is splendid! I oversimplified only a wee little bit but `str.replace(/<a href="([^"]+)" target="_blank">([^<]+)<\/a>/g, "$2{{link:$1}}")` clearly did the trick. Eternally grateful!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use dom methods. The dom is a better html parser than regex. This is a fairly simple `replaceWith`

```js
str = 'This is a <a href="test1.html">test</a>. And <a href="test2.html">another one</a> here.'

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
div.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=>{
    a.replaceWith(`${a.textContent}{{link:${a.getAttribute('href')}}}`)
})

console.log(div.innerHTML)
```

Comment: If you're on a browser or otherwise have a DOM parser available, this is the way to go in my book.

Comment: That's a very clever approach! Though it seems that in my case T.J. Crowder's solution is simpler, many thanks for widening my horizons.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right...I think OP's quill is a WYSIWYG editor

Comment: @AgustínDorado- FWIW, this is much more robust than the regex solution. :-)